# Is there a standard notation for a message concatenated with its signature?

Tags: signature, notation

I'm wondering what's the standard (or canonical) notation for "a message along with its signature", i.e.

$$
\mathit{Message}~\Vert~\sigma_k(\mathit{Message})
\text.
$$

Here the duplicated $\mathit{Message}$ is tedious. Is there a way to put it more elegantly?

Comment: I suppose you mean $$
 \mathit{Message}~\Vert~\sigma_k(\mathit{hash(Message)})
 \text.
 $$  Its called "signature with message recovery"

Comment: @Cryptostasis: what you describe is a message with its signature as appendix appended, and a degenerate form of signature with message recovery. Signature with message recovery is a more general concept, where the message (or some fraction of it) can be recovered from the signature. With RSA and small $M$, an example is $\sigma_{(e,d)}(M)=(M\|H(M))^d\bmod N$; or for something with provable reduction to the RSA problem, $\sigma_{(e,d)}(M)=(\operatorname{PRF}(M\|H(M)))^d\bmod N$ where the public PRF could be based on few rounds of a public Feistel transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formal papers, the standard way would be to either cleverly shorten it or to omit arguments.

For example you could write something like $M:=...$ (but please replace the dots with the actual message composition) at the end of your algorithm:
$$\operatorname{Output} (M||\sigma_K(M))$$

The alternative to this (a shortened version of your approach) would be to say that $\sigma$ is the signature in the text or define $\sigma$ somewhere and then use it as a simple variable. (outputting $(M||\sigma)$).

---

If you want to write a formal specification there are also ways to express a signed construct such as [TLS' `digitally-signed`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.7).